# UWP Windows 10 Phone Emulator

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, uwp

Whenever I try to debug my UWP projects with the a one of the Windows 10 Phone emulators I get the following error after the emulator opens to the home screen:
DEP6100; The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '90F4E8F4-EC5F-4B64-B2E8-6EDE6F813BD3'.': SEHException component has thrown an exception.

The app never starts. I have not entered any code. I simply create a UWP app and then try to debug it with the Windows 10 Phone emulator.[image: The Error window]

I have already uninstalled and reinstalled VS 2015. I even did a windows 10 repair.

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7bda1927-3aa5-4a3c-9268-5775e734addb/uwprunning-visual-studio-2015-rc-windows-10-universal-app-emulator-error-dep6100?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 1):

I get this the first time I debug an application. The trick I found is to do the following (precisely)

1. Make sure that your configuration settings are set to build and debug correctly (yes you need to check this UWP doesn't ship with it correctly configured)
2. Make sure the emulator is closed
3. Press the play button in visual studio
4. **As soon as the emulator appears** within visual studio, click on the build menu and hit cancel. This will stop deployment but the emulator will continue to boot.
5. Once the emulator has booted completely and you're able to navigate the OS, you're good to go. You can now run and debug your application normally.

NOTE: Don't close your emulator or you'll have to do this again. Just his stop in visual studio to stop debugging.